# How do I deal with the dimension problem in hierarchical Bayesian model like $P(q, v, B|x) = p(x|B) p(B|q, v) p(q, v)$?

Tags: bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian

How do I deal with the dimension problem in hierarchical Bayesian model like this?

$$ P(q, v, B|x) =  p(x|B) p(B|q, v) p(q, v)$$

The likelihood function has a 1D and 2D component, and the prior is a 2D matrix. How do they produce a 3D posterior?

Comment: As long as terms of the right hand side generates consistent dimensions for linear algebra

Comment: All the terms on the left hand side and on the right hand side are probabilities of some kind, i.e. real numbers between zero and one. There is no dimension mismatch problem. Note that you forgot one term $\frac{1}{p(x)}$.